# How to work on gradients from tf.compute_gradient?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to get at the values of the gradients computed by:

```py
grads_vars=optimizer.compute_gradients(loss,tf.trainable_variables())
```

The function 'compute_gradients' returns a two column list with some tf.gradient things, and some tf.variable things. I get an error when I try to fetch this list, since it's not a tensor.

Answer (score 0):

grads_and_vars is a list of tuples of tensors `[(gradient1, variable1), ...]`

But you can only fetch a list of tensors like `[gradient1, gradient2, ...]`, so you need to turn first list into second form

Comment: How can I fetch a list of tensors? I have _italic_ **bold** 'grads = [g_v[0] for g_v in grads_vars] ' 
  
  gg = tf.convert_to_tensor(grads)
  return gg' , then when I go to fetch it I get TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected.